# how do you determine correct dll for mongo php extension?

Tags: mongodb, dll

i'm having an issue loading the php extension for mongo.   i'm running windows 7 (32bt), with php 5.2.  i'm trying to update my php.ini file with the correct dll name, but not sure which of the dll's to use.  i know which php file to update.

the two sites i've found are:

https://github.com/stealth35/stealth35.github.com/downloads

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads

of these two sites, which windows (32bt) version am i to use?

any help on this would be much appreciated.   thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm going to recommend a 3rd place https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html

Now if you look in the latest version: php_mongo-1.4.5.zip (it has older versions there also) you'll see

```
php_mongo-1.4.5-5.2-vc9-nts.dll
php_mongo-1.4.5-5.2-vc9.dll
php_mongo-1.4.5-5.3-vc9-nts-x86_64.dll
php_mongo-1.4.5-5.3-vc9-nts.dll
php_mongo-1.4.5-5.3-vc9-x86_64.dll
php_mongo-1.4.5-5.3-vc9.dll
php_mongo-1.4.5-5.4-vc9-nts-x86_64.dll
php_mongo-1.4.5-5.4-vc9-nts.dll
php_mongo-1.4.5-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll
php_mongo-1.4.5-5.4-vc9.dll
php_mongo-1.4.5-5.5-vc11-nts-x86_64.dll
php_mongo-1.4.5-5.5-vc11-nts.dll
php_mongo-1.4.5-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll
php_mongo-1.4.5-5.5-vc11.dll
```

x86_64 are the 64 bit versions, since you are running 32 bit windows, you can ignore those, and the number that comes after 1.4.5(the mongo version) is the php version it expects aka 1.4.5-5.3 is php 5.3, mongo 1.4.5, so that narrows down the list to:

```
php_mongo-1.4.5-5.2-vc9-nts.dll
php_mongo-1.4.5-5.2-vc9.dll
```

vc9 refers to the visual studio it was compiled with, I believe vs9 is VS2008 ,and nts refers to "Non-Thread Safe" , if you are using threads use the php_mongo-1.4.5-5.2-vc9.dll ,

Place it in the "ext" directory for your php install(or wherever the extensions directory is) then add

```
extension=php_mongo-1.4.5-5.2-vc9.dll
```

or extension=php_mongo.dll (if you rename it to php_mongo.dll) to your php.ini

Comment: Downloads are available at https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb and should be more self explanatory by clicking on the `dll` link next to the .tgz , you can even download the specific dll.zip from that page.